# Configuring session timeout in WSO2 5.0 Identity Provider with multiple SP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have configured WSO2 5.0 server as an identity provider with 2 separate Service Providers on different domains. At the moment we're unable to properly configure our identity providers session timeout. We're setting the  param in /repository/conf/identity.xml - this seems to be connected with the samlssoTokenId cookie, and we're setting the  param in /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml file, which as far as we were able to determine, corresponds to Cache interval. We set both those values relatively low - 5min.

And here's our scenario:
On domain1 we try to access restricted content -> we're redirected to IdP login page, and after submitting proper credentials we're redirected back to SP page and we can see we're logged in. After waiting greater amount of time (~10min), we would expect, that trying to access restricted content on domain 2 would require submitting login credentials again on IdP page, but instead we're automaticly logged into domain2.

After some debugging we've established, that org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler obtains SessionContext from cache based on commonAuthId cookie value (which has session max-age). since we're setting the cache interval to 300 seconds, we would expect, that session data in cache should expire after that time, but it doesn't. Any ideas what we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware this is an old question and you've probably resolved this. So for pure reference:
 WSO2 IS 5.0.0 SP1 has an option to persist session key
 https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence